# Celery ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

We are creating an application which consists of a frontend (flask api) and a backend that uses celery. The API starts a celery task and retrieves the result like this:

```
result = data_source_tasks.add_data_point.delay(tok, uuid, source_type, datum, request_counter)
return result.get(timeout=5)
```

We use RabbitMQ as broker and result backend:

```
celery_broker_url = pyamqp://guest@localhost//
celery_result_backend = rpc://
```

After everything runs fine for a while (multiple thousand api calls) I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/connexion/decorators/decorator.py", line 66, in wrapper
    response = function(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/connexion/decorators/validation.py", line 122, in wrapper
    response = function(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/connexion/decorators/validation.py", line 293, in wrapper
    return function(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/connexion/decorators/decorator.py", line 42, in wrapper
    response = function(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/connexion/decorators/parameter.py", line 219, in wrapper
    return function(**kwargs)
  File "/mynedata/lib/api/apicalls.py", line 747, in store_datum
    return result.get(timeout=5)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/celery/result.py", line 224, in get
    on_message=on_message,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/celery/backends/async.py", line 188, in wait_for_pending
    for _ in self._wait_for_pending(result, **kwargs):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/celery/backends/async.py", line 255, in _wait_for_pending
    on_interval=on_interval):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/celery/backends/async.py", line 56, in drain_events_until
    yield self.wait_for(p, wait, timeout=1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/celery/backends/async.py", line 65, in wait_for
    wait(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/celery/backends/rpc.py", line 63, in drain_events
    return self._connection.drain_events(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 301, in drain_events
    return self.transport.drain_events(self.connection, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/kombu/transport/pyamqp.py", line 103, in drain_events
    return connection.drain_events(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 471, in drain_events
    while not self.blocking_read(timeout):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 476, in blocking_read
    frame = self.transport.read_frame()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 226, in read_frame
    frame_header = read(7, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 401, in _read
    s = recv(n - len(rbuf))
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

I can see in the console where I started the celery worker that the task (and all following tasks) succeeded, however, result.get results in a timeout for this and all following tasks. Did my connection to the result backend somehow break? If I restart the API, neither restarting the celery worker nor rabbitmq, everything works fine again.

Comment: It sounds like leak / flakiness after lots of exercise. I can't imagine that any of the upstream authors would be interested in debugging or patching such issues for a python3.4 environment. Consider reproducing your problem on a more recent version of python. Also, it would be helpful if you could boil it down and post short example code that lets us reproduce the symptom.

Comment: I will try and do that, starting by upgrading the python version :)

Comment: When we see this it's usually because we have too many connections open on the broker.  The easy work around for us was to remove the number of pooled threads for our broker to `1`.